# Uploading image as a base64String using Alamofire

Tags: ios, base64, swift4, alamofire, xcode10

iOS 12, Xcode: 10, Swift-4

Getting error while uploading a large size image as a Base64String to server.

Its working fine with small files

▿ some : AFError

```
▿ responseValidationFailed : 1 element
  ▿ reason : ResponseValidationFailureReason
    ▿ unacceptableStatusCode : 1 element
      - code : 413
```

I want to upload image as base64string only not as multi-part data.

Can you please guide me through ?

Comment: A statuscode 413 means that your request was too large. I assume you erroneously send your base64 string in your request instead of its body. But thats hard to tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may send your parameters in the request itself so the URI which created for your request becomes too long which is responsible for 413 server error.
you should send your parameters in the request body instead using this line of code:

`request.httpBody = parameters.percentEscaped().data(using: .utf8)`

Again I'll tell you to make sure that you don't append your parameters to the request url directly.